# Arduino Nano -- cannot download, no /dev/tty*** device

Tags: serial

It appears to me that each Arduino has (should have?) a unique /dev/tty...USB... number assigned. Why this isn't explained anywhere (that I can find) is a mystery. When I plug my problem Nano into a USB port on my iMac no /dev/tty... for it appears. It used to work. Have I fried it? Can this be fixed?

Comment: Check in system monitor or whatever they call it for unknown devices - you may have lost the FTDI (or whatever) driver.

Comment: Did you select the 'Nano' on the Tools->Board dropdown menu?

Comment: Sure. I have successfully programed a Micro and 2 other Nanos.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a duplicate question and duplicate answer, but ...

Flip the board over, look at the bottom. If it says "FTDI" then this answer doesn't apply. But many cheap clones have moved to the CH340G chip for USB serial communication, it's a tenth of the cost with a tenth of the (unused) features.

You can find CH340/341 drivers from the manufacturer at [WCH.CN](http://WCH.CN) or linked at the bottom of [this post](http://www.ardueasy.com/2014/10/different-varieties-of-arduino-nano.html).

Or, skip the USB altogether and search for "ISP" on [Tindie](https://Tindie.com) and grab a USBASP or TinyISP programmer.

Comment: My nano does not say FTDI on the bottom so I loaded the driver. Didn't work. I don't understand the Tindie ref.?

Comment: Do you at least get a power LED when you plug that device in? That should work independently. USBASP and TinyISP programmers (among other models) connect to the 2x3 pin header on the side opposite the USB connector and allow one to directly upload code, bypassing USB altogether.

Comment: Yes, the power light is on and the led labeled "L" on and off. If the 6 pins bypass USB then how would I access them from my iMac. BTW: I have 3 Arduinos that don't do the USB: old 1 Micro from Ada (FTDI, used to work, I must have fried it, still has power), 2 from Aliexpress @ $2.70 ea. (non-FTDI, poorly soldered pins). BTW: you might be interested in http://dicks-raspberry-pi.blogspot.com/ (my blog). Mostly Rpi but posts 66-68 about Aruino.